# Application fails to start after upgrading to Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have been trying to upgrade my application to Spring Boot 2. It compiles just fine but when I try to run it I get the below error in the logs. I'm not using `SpringApplicationBuilder` anywhere in my project, so not sure why that error is popping-up.

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:37843', transport: 'socket'
12:43:07.895 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle.... TONS OF FILE PATH LOGGING ....file:/opt/intellij/idea-IU-173.4301.25/lib/asm-all.jar]
12:43:08.188 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:120)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:62)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at com.freedompop.bdcp.appboy.Application.main(Application.java:31)
```

Comment: Do you have any spring dependencies where you are specifying the version?  Sounds like you are getting a mix of Spring 2 and Spring 1.5 or Spring 4 and Spring 5.

Comment: Did you also happen to update IntelliJ?

Comment: @JustinKSU - doing mvn dependency:tree | grep boot shows I'm on the same version of Spring Boot everywhere. Not sure what you mean by updating intelliJ? Even if I compile outside of IntelliJ, I get the same issue.

Comment: @DavidR What about Spring version though?

Comment: No references to Spring 4 anywhere.

Comment: Can you post your `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

This happen only when some spring dependencies is not compatible with Spring Boot 2.
To make it run either update those dependencies or update your parent in pom

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
 </parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely multiple similar jars in dependencies in effective pom can highlight the issue.